# how i can access google colab in my pc without RDP?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Here I want to know if can I access all of Google Colab's features just like Colab's internet speed and GPUs which I used on my pc without using any RDP.

Answer (score -1):

DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/0ARtbsJrzHf5E-l5eowqGJXek2W_2KOp3cDJArBtC7u1br3vDY4sjios03DW1rNEI4WcPFA" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).